# Add column that sums all previous rows that meet condition

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

say I have a large table of the following columns

```
   subject stim1 stim2 Chosen
1:       1     2     1      2
2:       1     3     2      2
3:       1     3     1      1
4:       1     2     3      3
5:       1     1     3      1
```

I'm looking for an efficient way (since the full data set is large) to mutate two additional columns (by subject)

1. stim1_seen, stim2_seen = is the sum of all prior instances in which the current stim1 was previously either in stim1 or stim2 (stim1_seen) or stim2 was previously in stim1 or stim2 (stim2_seen).
2. stim1_chosen, stim2_chosen= is the sum of all prior instances in which the current stim1 was chosen and the current stim2 was chosen respectively.

Desired output

```
     subject stim1 stim2 Chosen  stim1_chosen   stim2_chosen
1:       1     2     1      2         0               0
2:       1     3     2      2         0               1
3:       1     3     1      1         0               0
4:       1     2     3      3         2               0
5:       1     1     3      1         1               1
6:       1     2     1      1         2               2
```

ideally it'd be using data.table or dplyr.

here is the dput

```
structure(list(subject = c(1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021
), stim1 = c(51L, 48L, 49L, 48L, 49L, 46L), stim2 = c(50L, 50L, 
47L, 46L, 51L, 47L), Chosen = c(50L, 50L, 49L, 48L, 49L, 46L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fc9ce8158e0>)
```

Comment: Is this by `subject`?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a single pipe, demonstrated on both frames.

`dat1` is where you show some of the expected output

```r
dat1[, c("stim1_seen", "stim2_seen") :=
         lapply(.SD, function(z) mapply(function(x, S) {
           sum(stim1[S] %in% x | stim2[S] %in% x)
         }, z, lapply(seq_len(.N)-1, seq_len))),
     .SDcols = c("stim1", "stim2"), by = .(subject)
     ][, c("stim1_chosen", "stim2_chosen") :=
           lapply(.SD, function(z) mapply(function(x, S) {
             sum(Chosen[S] %in% x)
           }, z, lapply(seq_len(.N)-1, seq_len))),
       .SDcols = c("stim1", "stim2"), by = .(subject)]
#    subject stim1 stim2 Chosen stim1_seen stim2_seen stim1_chosen stim2_chosen
#      <int> <int> <int>  <int>      <int>      <int>        <int>        <int>
# 1:       1     2     1      2          0          0            0            0
# 2:       1     3     2      2          0          1            0            1
# 3:       1     3     1      1          1          1            0            0
# 4:       1     2     3      3          2          2            2            0
# 5:       1     1     3      1          2          3            1            1
# 6:       1     2     1      1          3          3            2            2
```

`dat2` is your dput output (different data)

```r
dat2[, c("stim1_seen", "stim2_seen") :=
         lapply(.SD, function(z) mapply(function(x, S) {
           sum(stim1[S] %in% x | stim2[S] %in% x)
         }, z, lapply(seq_len(.N)-1, seq_len))),
     .SDcols = c("stim1", "stim2"), by = .(subject)
     ][, c("stim1_chosen", "stim2_chosen") :=
           lapply(.SD, function(z) mapply(function(x, S) {
             sum(Chosen[S] %in% x)
           }, z, lapply(seq_len(.N)-1, seq_len))),
       .SDcols = c("stim1", "stim2"), by = .(subject)]
#    subject stim1 stim2 Chosen stim1_seen stim2_seen stim1_chosen stim2_chosen
#      <num> <int> <int>  <int>      <int>      <int>        <int>        <int>
# 1:    1021    51    50     50          0          0            0            0
# 2:    1021    48    50     50          0          1            0            1
# 3:    1021    49    47     49          0          0            0            0
# 4:    1021    48    46     48          1          0            0            0
# 5:    1021    49    51     49          1          1            1            0
# 6:    1021    46    47     46          1          1            0            0
```

---

The heavy-effort here is trying to do a "cumulative `%in%`". In effect, that's what `mapply` is doing.

- knowing that `data.table`'s `.N` special symbol provides the number of rows in a group, then this is useful:

  ```r
  lapply(seq_len(.N)-1, seq_len)
  # [[1]]
  # integer(0)
  # [[2]]
  # [1] 1
  # [[3]]
  # [1] 1 2
  # [[4]]
  # [1] 1 2 3
  # [[5]]
  # [1] 1 2 3 4
  # [[6]]
  # [1] 1 2 3 4 5
  ```

  This is used to index all rows before each row; that is, in row 1, there are no preceding rows, so we index on `integer(0)`; in row 5, we index on `1 2 3 4`; etc.
- we "zip" that together (using `mapply`) along with each `stim1` (and then `stim2` value, to look for presence in the original `stim1` and `stim2` columns *indexed on `S`* (from the previous bullet), and sum the occurrences
- finally, we do this for both of the `stim*` columns by iterating over `.SD` (using `.SDcols`)
- this process is repeated (albeit more simply) on the `Chosen` column

---

Data

```r
dat1 <- setDT(structure(list(subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), stim1 = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), stim2 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), Chosen = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L)))
dat2 <- setDT(structure(list(subject = c(1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021), stim1 = c(51L, 48L, 49L, 48L, 49L, 46L), stim2 = c(50L, 50L, 47L, 46L, 51L, 47L), Chosen = c(50L, 50L, 49L, 48L, 49L, 46L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this works on the sample data. It would be good to run it on some where we have more subjects and have values greater than 1 in the columns. I've assumed its a `data.table` object called `dt`

**1. Index**

Really easy to change row ordering with `merge` operations, so never rely on row numbers, but instead create a `rowid` by `subject`. `.N` is data.table syntax for the length/number of rows.

```
# order matters, so make a rowid
dt[, rowid := 1:.N, by=subject]

# sets orders and indexing to make it quicker
setkey(dt, subject, rowid)
```

**2. Seen cols**

Need to merge the `stim1` and `stim2` in to one column. Do so by going from a wide to long format with `melt`.
`seen:=0:(.N-1)` is then grouped by these values to find the cumulative occurrences by row. But as we're looking at prior values, we subtract 1.

Then we do two merges as we're interested in comparing this with both stim cols

```
# for seen, melt wide to long
dt_seen <- melt(dt, 
                id.vars = c("subject", "rowid"), 
                measure.vars = c("stim1", "stim2"))
# interested in finding occurences
dt_seen <- unique(dt_seen[, .(subject, rowid, value)])
setorder(dt_seen, rowid)
dt_seen[, seen:=0:(.N-1), by=.(subject, value)]

# merge across twice
dt <- merge(dt, dt_seen, 
            by.x=c("subject", "rowid", "stim1"), 
            by.y=c("subject", "rowid", "value"), 
            all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE)
setnames(dt, "seen", "stim1_seen")
dt <- merge(dt, dt_seen, 
            by.x=c("subject", "rowid", "stim2"), 
            by.y=c("subject", "rowid", "value"), 
            all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE)
setnames(dt, "seen", "stim2_seen")
dt[]
```

**3. Chosen**

I've been lazy and done effectively the same as in section (2), but first filtering to rows where Chosen matches the stim value. And doing one by one instead of together as these cols are independent. The process is identical for stim1 and stim2, so could tidy it up slightly.

```
# turn Chosen from wide to long
dt_chosen <- melt(dt,
                  id.vars = c("subject", "rowid"), 
                  measure.vars = c("Chosen"))
# interested in finding occurences
# need to expand 
dt_chosen[, variable := NULL]
# going to expand the grid, so can look at e.g. value 50 for all rowids
library(tidyr)
dt_chosen[, chosen_row := 1]
dt_chosen_full <- expand(dt_chosen, nesting(subject, rowid), value) %>% setDT
# pull in the actual data and fill rest with 0's
dt_chosen_full <- merge(dt_chosen_full, dt_chosen, by=c("subject", "rowid", "value"),
                        all.x=TRUE)
dt_chosen_full[is.na(chosen_row), chosen_row := 0]
# use cumsum to identify now the cumulative count of these across the full row set
dt_chosen_full[, chosen := cumsum(chosen_row), by=.(subject, value)]
# as its prior, on the row itself, subtract one so the update happens after the row
dt_chosen_full[chosen_row==1, chosen := chosen-1]

# merge across twice
dt <- merge(dt, dt_chosen_full[, -"chosen_row"], 
            by.x=c("subject", "rowid", "stim1"), 
            by.y=c("subject", "rowid", "value"), 
            all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE)
setnames(dt, "chosen", "stim1_chosen")
dt[is.na(stim1_chosen), stim1_chosen := 0]

dt <- merge(dt, dt_chosen_full[, -"chosen_row"], 
            by.x=c("subject", "rowid", "stim2"), 
            by.y=c("subject", "rowid", "value"), 
            all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE)
setnames(dt, "chosen", "stim2_chosen")
dt[is.na(stim2_chosen), stim2_chosen := 0]
```

**Output**

```
dt[]
   subject rowid stim2 stim1 Chosen stim1_seen stim2_seen stim1_chosen stim2_chosen
1:    1021     1    50    51     50          0          0            0            0
2:    1021     2    50    48     50          0          1            0            1
3:    1021     3    47    49     49          0          0            0            0
4:    1021     4    46    48     48          1          0            0            0
5:    1021     5    51    49     49          1          1            1            0
6:    1021     6    47    46     46          1          1            0            0
```

Comment: it worked perfectly for times seen but didn't work for times chosen. i put up a different example in my question that should include more than just 0 and 1.
thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, I've re-done section 3 now. I didn't use the new data, but if it doesn't work, please add a `dput` for it. But I think it should work. I'm mostly concerned about the size of data in the `expand` section. How large is your full data?